# createQueryBuilder with Join in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

If I do this:

```
        ->select('a')
        ->from('AppBundle:Accomodation', 'a')
        ->innerJoin('AppBundle:AccomodationRoom', 'ap', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('ap.accomodation', 'a.id'))
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

all the fields in Accomodation are selected.
But if I add this 'ap' to the select, as below, it doesn't select the Accomodation fields:

```
        ->select('a', 'ap')
        ->from('AppBundle:Accomodation', 'a')
        ->innerJoin('AppBundle:AccomodationRoom', 'ap', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('ap.accomodation', 'a.id'))
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The relation between entities. This is Accomodation:
    /**

```
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AccomodationRoom", mappedBy="accomodation")
 */
private $rooms;
```

And this is AccomodationRoom:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Accomodation", inversedBy="rooms")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="accomodation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $accomodation;
```

Please, any idea?

Comment: Could you show your Accomodation and AccomodationRoom entities? You need to specify relations between them so you will not need Join::WITH.

Comment: I updated with the annotations info. Any help is welcome @jaro1989

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `select` Accomodation and AccomodationRooms.

```
    ->select('a', 'ap')
    ->from('AppBundle:Accomodation', 'a')
    ->innerJoin('a.rooms', 'ap')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: It throws this error: Warning: Missing argument 2 for Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::innerJoin(), called in /src/AppBundle/Repository/AccomodationRepository.php on line 28 and defined

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Now it throws this: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got 'FROM'. I'm a little bit lost, I saw many examples like this but in my case it doesn't work

Comment: Ah! I now think I know whats going on: you _do_ need `->select('a', 'ap')`. I think you're using the QueryBuilder without any repository, do you?

Comment: Yeah, now it works! Thank you so much! Just one more question... I was in the way to get the min(ap.price) and groupby (a.id)... how should I put the "min(ap.price) as minprice" on the select clause, because it throws another different error...

Comment: I updated the answer again, which you should be able to accept now. For the other error, the error message would be helpful (and your code). Could you therefore create a new question please?

Comment: Thanks! I've opened this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684744/how-to-select-the-min-value-with-leftjoin-in-doctrine-using-query-builder, if you could take a look I appreciate. Thanks..