# How to select the min value with leftJoin in Doctrine using query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Trying to do a leftJoin, getting the lowes price value in the second with a groupBy on the first table:

```
        ->select('a', 'ap')
        ->from('AppBundle:Accomodation', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('a.rooms', 'ap')
        ->groupBy ('a.id')
        ->orderBy('a.name','ASC')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And when I try this below, it doesn't fetch the data (trhows error on Twig: field a.name doesn't exist):

```
        ->select('a', $qb->expr()->min('ap.price'))
        ->from('AppBundle:Accomodation', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('a.rooms', 'ap')
        ->groupBy ('a.id')
        ->orderBy('a.name','ASC')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Annotations in both entities are these:

Accomodation.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AccomodationRoom", mappedBy="accomodation")
 */
private $rooms;
```

AccomodationRoom.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Accomodation", inversedBy="rooms")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="accomodation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $accomodation;
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Presumably the property `name` exists within the `AppBundle:Accomodation` entity?

Comment: Right, it exists...

Comment: Please could you show us the bit of the database schema and the entity that relate to `name`

Comment: But the error message is complaining about `a.name`, please could you show us that part.

Comment: name is just a string field of Accomodation, it retrieves data ok in the first try, but not in the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe what's happening in the first example is that if your `Accomodation` entity has the property "rooms" then doctrine will not populate the results using separate array keys for "a" and "ap" because "rooms" is returned in the parent entity "accomodation".

```
$result = $query
    ->select('user', 'posts')
    ->from('MyBundle:User', 'user')
    ->leftJoin('a.posts', 'posts')
    ->groupBy ('user.id')
    ->orderBy('user.name','ASC')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Will result in a single-dimensional array of users. I don't even think you need the left join since doctrine will auto-load the related entity when you try to access it.

Now in your second example (the broken one) the second argument to select() is no longer a related entity, but a scalar value. In this case Doctrine **will** return a multidimensional array

```
$result = $query
    ->select('user', $qb->expr()->min('posts.length'))
    ->from('MyBundle:User', 'user')
    ->leftJoin('a.posts', 'posts')
    ->groupBy ('user.id')
    ->orderBy('user.name','ASC')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Has the form

```
[
    [
        0 => $user,
        1 => $minLength
    ],
    [
        0 => $user,
        1 => $minLength
    ],
    ...
]
```

Which will break your twig template since you're looping on the top level of the array. To make things nicer in twig you might want to use aliases in your result, so something like:

```
$query
    ->select('a as accomodation', 'MIN(ap.price) as minPrice')
    ->from('AppBundle:Accomodation', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('a.rooms', 'ap')
    ->groupBy ('a.id')
    ->orderBy('a.name','ASC')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

will give you:

```
[
    [
        'accomodation' => $accomodation,
        'minPrice' => $minPrice
    ],
    [
        'accomodation' => $accomodation,
        'minPrice' => $minPrice
    ],
    ...
]
```

(You can't use min as an alias because it's a reserved word)

Then you can change your twig template to reference the aliases which makes things more explicit

Comment: Great! it was a two-dimensional array. The easiest solution in this case is to do this: {% set accomodation = item[0] %} just inside the loop in Twig. Thanks a lot, great and detailed answer!

Comment: Glad it helped. To help you with these kinds of problems in the future I'd recommend looking into debugging (xdebug or simple `var_dump` in Symfony and `dump` in twig